# Thymeleaf dropdown not populating although it is able to populate in a dynamic table

Tags: spring-boot, dynamic, thymeleaf, dropdown

[Picture for referece:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4mF5.png) Here is the Thymeleaf code:

```
<tr>
        <label class="form-label">Employee ID</label>
    <select name="Employee">
        <option value="">Select Employee</option>
        <option
        th:each="Employee : ${listEmployees}"
        th:text="${firstname}">     
        </option>
    </select>
    </tr>
```

Updated:

```
<tr>
        <label class="form-label">Employee ID</label>
        <select name="Employee">
        <option value="">Select Employee</option>
        <option
        th:each="Employee : ${listEmployees}"
        th:value="${Employee.employeenum}"
        th:text="${Employee.firstname}">        
        </option>
    </select>
    </tr>
```

I know for a fact everything else is working because I have been able to populate it into a dynamic table. I am certain my problem is with the HTML.

Controller

```
package com.example.app.controller;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.example.app.model.Employee;
import com.example.app.service.EmployeeService;

@RestController
public class EmployeeRestController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;
    
    @RequestMapping
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployeees(){
            return employeeService.getAllEmployees();
    }
    

    
}
```

Controller

```
package com.example.app.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

import com.example.app.service.EmployeeService;

@Controller
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeService employeeService;
    

    
    //display list of employees
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String ViewHomePage(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("listEmployees", employeeService.getAllEmployees());
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Employee Model

```
package com.example.app.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="building_locations")
public class BuildingAssignments {

    @Id
    @Column(name="employee_number")
    public int employeenumb;
    @Column(name="buildingID")
    public String buildingname;
    @Column(name="building_address")
    public String buildingadd;
    
    public int getEmployeenumb() {
        return employeenumb;
    }
    public void setEmployeenumb(int employeenumb) {
        this.employeenumb = employeenumb;
    }
    public String getBuildingname() {
        return buildingname;
    }
    public void setBuildingname(String buildingname) {
        this.buildingname = buildingname;
    }
    public String getBuildingadd() {
        return buildingadd;
    }
    public void setBuildingadd(String buildingadd) {
        this.buildingadd = buildingadd;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "BuildingAssignments [employeenumb=" + employeenumb + ", buildingname=" + buildingname + ", buildingadd="
                + buildingadd + "]";
    }
```

And I have this linked to another html page as well that is working with a dynamic table with the mysql database that I'm linked to.

Comment: There is a stray `<td>` tag in the code in the question. Is this drop-down supposed to be in a table? The fact that you also have a `<label>` suggests this is not intended to be used in a table... Otherwise, assuming your Thymeleaf variables are correct, then your template code looks OK to me. If you want to show a pre-selected value, you also need `th:selected="..."`. (Minor note: you have single quotes for the class name. For consistency, use double-quotes.)

Comment: You can also [edit] the question to show the actual (non-functioning) HTML which gets generated. You can use the browser inspector (F12) to grab that.

Comment: @andrewJames  I updated the code and I'm still not getting anything populating. I am going to updated with the actual HTML that's not generating. Thanks for the tip so far.

Comment: This does not look like an HTML problem. It looks like the Java employee list is empty and/or it is not being passed to the Thymeleaf template correctly. You may get better help if you show the relevant code for that.

Comment: @andrewJames In the same program, I am loading the same information into a table with a different  GetMapping, and the information from my database is showing up correctly there.  I'll add more code.

Comment: @andrewJames added. I also have a simple repository and service. Again all working correctly.

Comment: Thank you for the updates. I see a typo in `public List<Employee> getAllEmployeees()`. Apart from that, if you are sure `employeeService.getAllEmployees()` is returning a non-empty list, then I don't know where the issue is.

Comment: @andrewJames I figured it out finally. It was a problem in my controller. I didn't add the attribute to pull the employees from the database.